# is it possible to draw a layout and convert to bitmap without being visible

Tags: android, bitmap, draw

I'm trying to convert an layout view to image\bitmap and save in the device.

I'know how to convert a view to a bitmap, like this

```
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```

The above code works great if your view already has been drawn however, I don't want to make the view to be drew. I don't want the user to see it. I want it directly to be saved to the device without the need of display the view.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Something like this will work:

```
    Bitmap scene = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scene);
    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
```

w is the width of the bitmap, h its height.  You might want to set those using the measured height and with of the view in which the bitmap will be displayed.

The last line just demonstrates drawing a rectangle

Comment: I want to draw a view not rectangle. so I want to prepare a view in layout and inflate it then save it.

Comment: What do you mean by "draw a view"??  When a View draws itself, it draws on a Canvas.  Anything that a View can draw, you can draw on the above bitmap.  Save the bitmap and draw it whenever you like.